# No method "mouseover " - Protractor

Tags: unit-testing, mouseevent, protractor

I've searched the docs and google and am struggling to find solid references to how one is supposed to write an E2E test for ngMouseenter events. Angular's E2E testing tools has element(selector, label).mouseover() but it is not working.

```
element.all(by.css('.classic-menu-dropdown ul li')).then(function(items) {
    items[2].mouseover();
    element.all(by.css('.dropdown-menu li')).then(function(items) {
        items[2].click();
    }); 
    ptor.sleep(500);
});
```

I've got

> Message:
>   Object [object Objecct] has no method "mouseover"

Could anyone suggest me how to test ngMouseenter event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this helps!(https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/159):

```
ptor.actions().
mouseMove(ptor.findElement(protractor.B.id('foo'))).
perform();
```

Comment: As per my requirement i added as follows but it won't work `element.all(by.css('.classic-menu-dropdown li')).then(function(items) {
    ptor.actions().
    mouseMove(items[2]).
    perform();
    element.all(by.css('.dropdown-menu li')).then(function(items) {
 items[2].click();
    }); 
    ptor.sleep(500);
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ptor = browser.driver;
ptor.actions().mouseMove(ptor.findElement(by.css("CSS to dropdown menu - main label"))).perform();
ptor.findElement(by.css("submenu")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake. Instead of `items[2].mouseover();` you should use `items.get(2).mouseover();`